# Relational Database One Relationship triggers another relationship

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

Thanks in advance.
I am learning and designing a RDBMS of an organization with 2 departments .
Its pretty straightforward but the problem arises when an action in one department leads to action in the other department . Suppose department one does survey of consumers and this survey causes department 2 to introduce a product. The trouble is I have no idea how to connect this relationships of surveying and introducing new products together. I am learning RDBMS on my own.

Comment: So are you talking about Database Triggers or Foreign Keys.  I believe you are speaking of the latter.

Comment: Yes. I did some research online and came up with the term aggregation which I believe is for relationship between relationship. Can foreign keys be used in situation when it requires aggregation in ER diagram

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to model a scenario where you can track a department's actions to the records that they create, whether that record is a product or a survey.  I have attached a diagram and will attempt to explain the relationships.

Each department can have a number of different actions.  These actions can be shared across departments.  Every DepartmentAction can have an associated ActionEntity.  This ActionEntity shares a 1 to 0..1 relationship with both Product and Survey.  Finally, every product and survey can also have the department's id that created the record.

[image]